# Text in modal body not showing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am braking my head why the text "*Text for privacy Policy*" in my modal body is not called? The text has to be in the body of the modal. At the moment the body is just blank. I have made a [JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/h9curfkd/). What am I missing here?

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(' ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-content').val(recipient)
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">GENERAL</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Privatpolitik">Privacy Policy</a><br/>
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Privacy Policy</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        Text for privacy Policy
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a `modal` nested within your `modal-body`. That ain't gonna work.

Comment: The modal says Privatpolitik - the body is not a formfield so change ` modal.find('.modal-content').val(recipient)` to `modal.find('.modal-content').text(recipient)`

Comment: @mplungjan The body of the modal is blank. "Privatpolitik" is the modal header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one modal-content. You need something else.

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var recipient = button.data('whatever')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(' ! ' + recipient)
  modal.find('#textbody').html(recipient)
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">GENERAL</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="Privatpolitik">Privacy Policy</a><br/>
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Privacy Policy</h4>
                  <div id="textbody"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Luk</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```